# Go to the next available record in dataset

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have the following code which goes to the next available record to process.

```
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim strListType As String = Request.QueryString("ListType")
        Dim strStatusFilter As String = ""
        Select Case strListType
            Case "newmember"
                strStatusFilter = "Status_Ind in (1,4,6,8) and IsMember_Ind=1"
            Case "nonmember"
                strStatusFilter = "Status_Ind in (1,4,6,8) and IsMember_Ind=1"
            End Select

        ds = objClass.List(0, 10, "Due_Dt, Joined_Date ASC", "", strStatusFilter)

       'go to the next record
        If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
            Server.Transfer("Request.aspx?Request_ID=" & ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Request_ID") & "&ListType=" & strListType)
        Else
            Server.Transfer("List.aspx?Status=NewMember")
        End If
```

ObjClass.List is a method which is implemented to run a view and filter out data. I am ordering data on two columns due_dt and joined_dt.

My problem is that it goes to the same record everytime if I didnt update my due date. I just want to go to the next record if  am not updating it. Ho can I have the behaviour I want? what changes I can make?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following statement returns the first row in the table:

```
ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("Request_ID")
```

To get the second row, you could use this statement:

```
ds.Tables(0).Rows(1).Item("Request_ID")
```

To loop through all the rows, you could do something like this:

```
For Each row As DataRow in ds.Tables(0).Rows
    Dim requestId As Object = row.Item("Request_ID")
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.... This should work.... first you have to declare a static variable called data_row and also a dataset.

> public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>           {
>               if (RowNo < sqlDst.Tables["news"].Rows.Count - 1)
>               {
>                   RowNo += 1;
>                   DataRow drow = sqlDst.Tables["news"].Rows[RowNo];
>
> ```
>             Label2.Text = drow.ItemArray.GetValue(0).ToString();
>             TextBox2.Text = drow.ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString();
>             Label1.Text = "";
>
>         }
>
>         else
>         {
>             Label1.Text = "No more records";
>         }
>
>     }
> ```

for this to work need to declare variables at the top of the page.

> private DataSet sqlDst = new DataSet();
>           private static int RowNo = 0;
>           businesscheck obj1 = new businesscheck();